# How to know under what Node.js version work a given package

Tags: npm

Lets say I have express.js v3.16.9, how can I know under what node version will it work in order to know if I have to downgrade or upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would search for the source code of that version; specifically looking for the package.json and check its dependencies. Hopefully there you will find some info.

For express v3.16.9 the sources are at https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/3.16.9 (or you could just install it and look in your node_modules). From the sources package.json I can see the following;

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
}
```

This does not work all the time, as not all packages declare their engine requirement, so YMMV

Comment: You're right, after discussing with a senior colleague he also pointed me out this option as the only way to know from the code itself. I don't like this is not a "common" practice, but it is what it is. Thanks Joel.

Answer (score 0):

[As suggested on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561124/6488602) you can do the following to see what engine versions a package supports

```bash
npm view express@3.16.9 engines
# you can also omit the version specifier to get the latest version
npm view express engines
```

Not every package specifies an `engines` field in their `package.json`, but express does. For your specific version it requires `{ node: '>= 0.8.0' }`