# How to find compatible dependency version for a given nodeJS version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, upgrade, npm-package

Suppose I am upgrading my node version from **14 LTS** to **16.18.1 LTS** version. After that I need to upgrade my react project node modules to latest & compatible versions.
Can anyone advice me how to find out compatible version of a node module for a given node version?

Answer (score 9):

Hope I understood you correctly. you can use the `npm view <package_name>` command to see more information about what is required.

If you want to know what dependencies React 17.0.1 requires you can use these commands and get these outputs

```
npm view react@17.0.1 dependencies 
{ 'loose-envify': '^1.1.0', 'object-assign': '^4.1.1' }

npm view react@17.0.1 engines
{ node: '>=0.10.0' }
```

Then you know you what dependency versions and node versions you require.
You can do the same with `npm view <package> peerDependencies`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. This was helpful. By the way my action items are as below. I am running a react 16 project on top of node 14 LTS. Now I wanted to upgrade react to 17 or 18. My fist assumption is in order to upgrade to react 17 or 18 i have to upgrade node version to 16 or 18 LTS. Then I have to upgrade dependencies to compatible versions which maps with node version. Lets say 'axios' should updated to  from 0.21.1 to 1.2.0. In the axios git hub page can I find node version which is compatible with given axios version. Like that I need to analyze all the dependencies.

Comment: Very helpful. Saved a lot of time.